# i am getting a result from my api(express) after submission of form in react but page is throwing error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

i am getting on page after submission of form .I am Submitting Form I am getting response from by express API . But by page is getting broken . I have tried to change value of field to include a string e.g Value={data.username || ''} . But still getting error "cannot read property length of undefined "

Below is the screenshot of error i am getting on submission .
note: new to react

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfuGD.png

below is my link to codepen

```
https://codepen.io/LuckyShubham/pen/XWpyPar
```

Comment: `data.username` is undefined. So, you are trying to get the length of something that is undefined. Therefore the error. Add a null check for `data.username` before trying to get its length. You will not get the error.

Comment: Please check your <CForm> component where the username object that is assigned to data is undefined, and hence it is throwing this exception

Comment: @TomBombadil  Sorry Didnt get resolved ... I have given a link to code pen for my Component...Thanks

Comment: `if (data.username != null)` make this `if (data.username)` You are checking only for null, while `data.username` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
Value={data?.username || ''}
```

add it like this so when data loads your use-effect will re-render the component with data.

Comment: Sorry Didnt get resolved ... I have given a link to code pen for my Component...Thanks